# Whitespace at top of webpage

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with around 20px of whitespace at the top of my webpage. It is hard to see but when you inspect element you can see the little gap at the top.

[www.craigengland.co.uk](http://www.craigengland.co.uk)

I have adopted

```
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
```

but to no avail

Any suggestions?

I have tried "normalize" locally and it still doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: you can add css for your svg : body svg{ display: none; } or in html <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="width:0; height:0; visibility:hidden;display: none;">

Comment: Please include a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @Gregorie that worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, good luck

Comment: **visibility: hidden** only stops the specific element from being rendered, but it still occupies the same space in the layout.

Answer (score 4):

svg tag content after the body tag and before the header tag is causing that. Remove that whitespace issue will be fixed or if you want to do this using CSS, Add the following code to your css file.

```
svg{display:none;}
```

Comment: *"svg tag content after the tag and before the is causing that. Remove that whitespace issue will be fixed"* Eventhough it makes no sense, the answer is correct

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it is before the header tag.

Comment: Yes if you wish you can add that inline style of that svg tag. Both will work.

Comment: Had to edit last comment, I misunderstood your reply

Comment: No Problem, Sorry for my typo.

Answer (score 2):

Add `style="display: none"` to your svg element and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `margin-top` from `header`.

```
 header {
    margin: 14% 0 0; /* remove this from main.css */
}
```

Comment: This in combination with `svg` is causing all the top whitespace issues.

Answer (score 0):

well, while inspecting your web page. its show this whitspace in the header because of the margin you have given to it in the css

> margin: 14% 0 0% 0%;

when I disable the margin you have given, the white space is no more to be seen . Header tag looks fine without that margin setting you gave.

I don't see any other error!